# Unable ( or able) to List<int>.Cast<Enum>()?

Tags: c#

Try the following code

```
public enum Color
{
    Blue=1,
    Red=2, 
    Green=3 
}

public List<Color> ConvertColorEnum()
{
    var intColor = new List<int>(){1,2,3};
    return intColor.Cast<Color>().ToList();
}
```

Do you think the `ConvertColorEnum()` will return a list of color, i.e., `List<Color>(){Color.Blue, Color.Red, Color.Green}`?

I tested this on 2 machines, one with .net 3.5 ( mscorlib version 2.0.50727.1433), another with .net 3.5 SP1 ( mscorlib version 2.0.50727.3082). The results were different-- the .net 3.5 threw an `InvalidCastException` because couldn't convert integer to enum, whereas .net 3.5 SP1 could run successfully, with correct results returned.

Anyone would like to try this on his/her machine and report the result or explain why this is so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read about the difference between the SP1 and the original release of the .net 3.5 framework [in the release notes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd310284.aspx).

Here's what it says for this particular issue:

> In LINQ query expressions over
>   non-generic collections such as
>   System.Collections.ArrayList, the from
>   clause of the query is rewritten by
>   the compiler to include a call to the
>   Cast  operator. Cast converts
>   all element types to the type
>   specified in the from clause in the
>   query. In addition, in the original
>   release version of Visual C# 2008, the
>   Cast operator also performs some
>   value type conversions and
>   user-defined conversions. However,
>   these conversions are performed by
>   using the System.Convert class instead
>   of the standard C# semantics. These
>   conversions also cause significant
>   performance issues in certain
>   scenarios. In Visual C# 2008 SP1, the
>   Cast operator is modified to throw
>   an InvalidCastException for numeric
>   value type and user-defined
>   conversions. This change eliminates
>   both the non-standard C# cast
>   semantics and the performance issue.
>   This change is illustrated in the
>   following example.

You can also get more details in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ed_maurer/archive/2008/02/16/breaking-change-in-linq-queries-using-explicitly-typed-range-variables.aspx).

Answer (score 26):

If you want it to work either way, use `Select` instead.

```
return intColor.Select(i=>(Color)i).ToList();
```

As for the why...?

Comment: @marc, I about to say grats on the 50K but your painfully close at 49,999 ;)

Comment: Good idea, but don't you think that intColor.Cast<Color>() is more succinct and readable?

Comment: why covered in my answer - the acceptance on this one will push you over the top ;)

Comment: @Ngu is is more readable but it *isn't* what is happening so is a bit of a bad idea... it *says* it's a cast but it's actually a box and cast which is different

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui: actually, I was surprised that the Cast<> version worked! I wouldn't have any expectation of that working, so no: I don't think it is more readable.

Comment: @Marc congrats you are now > 10 times my rep, ah the joys of order of magnitude ;)

Answer (score 5):

The Cast extension method makes use of an iterator which, on move next, stores the output of the original enumerator in an object variable (so boxing as needed) then attempts to cast that to the result type.

Value types in boxed form do not respond to the cast operation in the same way they would if they were unboxed (where various automatic conversions are possible) instead they only allow casting to their original unboxed form.

I would imagine that the previous implementation of the Cast extension was either doing it completely differently or had some special casing for enum types to convert to an integral form (this is tricky as you must deal with all possible forms)

Marc's answer as to the correct solution is completely correct and is actually more efficient than the cast anyway for the aforementioned boxing reasons.

Comment: Ah yes, <obj>5__ab - I didn't spot that one ;-p

Comment: easy to miss - gotta love compiler synthesized names, I wish MS made it easier to just down load the whole source - Maybe I should write a reflector plugin soemtime to grab it from the symbol server...